# GPG Key Created But WIll Not Decrypt

Tags: launchpad, gnupg

I created a GPG key with Ubuntu 16.04's "Passwords and Keys" and pushed it to the Ubuntu server.   I tried to import into Launchpad, but when I got the email to decrypt, I keep getting an error saying  'gpg: decryption failed: secret key not available'

I have encrypt subkey and sign,certify subkey.   I've tried to see if there was a way to add a decrypt subkey, but I am not seeing it under the gui.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: GnuPG is not aware of the secret key. Are you using the same computer for decryption you used for key creation? Did you create the key under the same user account? What's the output of `gpg -K`?

Comment: Yes I created this key on this machine/user about a week ago.

gpg -K (capitalized) returns nothing. but lowercased it returns:

/home/username/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
----------------------------
pub   2048R/F5E1B7DE 2016-05-08
uid                  TR Precht <email1@gmail.com>
uid                  Travis Precht<email1@gmail.com>
uid                  [jpeg image of size 3928]
sub   2048R/47D28DC1 2016-05-08

Comment: If it is missing in `gpg -K` (the long version for `-K` is `--list-secret-keys`, `-k` with a small letter only lists public keys), GnuPG does not find the secret keys. Also try `gpg2 -K` and `sudo -H gpg -K` (to make sure you didn't create the key as root by accident).

Comment: gpg2 -K seemed to work.

I was able to decypt using 'gpg2' instead of gpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> gpg2 -K seemed to work. I was able to decypt using 'gpg2' instead of gpg

Then you're already using GnuPG 2.1, which stores the secret keys in the `pubring.gpg`. Either never use `gpg` (GnuPG 1) at all, or copy the secret key to `secring.gpg` used by GnuPG 1 by exporting and importing it:

```
gpg2 --export-secret-keys [key-id] | gpg --import
```

You might also need to apply ultimate trust to the key:

```
gpg --edit-key [key-id]
```

On the GnuPG command line, now run the `trust` command and select `ultimate`.